# Watch for environment variable change - ZSH

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, zsh

Is there a way to watch for changes to an environment variable in zsh/bash? When switching my kubernetes environment, for example, I would like to be able to read the variable that's set and make changes to my terminal window if I'm in production vs. development etc.

The way we switch environments is part of our tooling. I'd like to be able to extend that on my own machine without having to update any tooling. If watching for an environment variable change isn't possible, I'm also looking for a way to use something similar to `builtin`.

`Example: create a function of the same name as an alias, call that alias from within the function, then do some other action afterward.`

Comment: If you want to e.g. update the terminal title based on a variable, you'd typically just output the ansi sequence on every prompt. There's no point listening to changes to variables since these changes can only be made by the shell itself, and not by any external process.

Comment: What I'd like to do, to be more precise, is update the background color of the terminal to red (separate variable) if I've entered into a production environment or back to dark if I'm in a development environment

Comment: Do a `man terminfo`

Comment: You could use the `precmd` hook in `zsh` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `bash` to check the value and respond appropriately. Neither shell has a hook to specifically monitor a given variable.

Comment: @chepner thanks for this, this was perfect. Would you like to make this an answer that I can mark as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both shells provide a way to execute arbitrary code prior to displaying a prompt; you can use this to check the value of a specific variable and take an appropriate action.

In `.bashrc`:

```
# The function name doesn't matter; it's just easier
# to set PROMPT_COMMAND to the name of a function than
# to arbitrary code.
pre_prompt () {
    if [[ $SOME_VAR == "prod" ]]; then
        doSomething
    else [[
        doSomethingElse
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=pre_prompt
```

In `.zshrc`:

```
precmd () {
    if [[ $SOME_VAR == "prod" ]]; then
        doSomething
    else [[
        doSomethingElse
    fi
}
```